# Why do some browsers render this unicode character using the wrong font, apparently at random?

Tags: html, web, browser, fonts

I am developing a website which requires use of the unicode symbol "S with caron" (0x161).  The website uses the free Palanquin font, which does support this character - however, some machines incorrectly render this particular character in a different font.  For example:

[image: Example of incorrect renedering]

Note that in the incorrect example, the correct font is being used for other characters, even for those containing unusual diacritics.  Crucially though, **there is no obvious pattern about which machines are affected**.  Using browsershots.org, I have seen the issue occur on Chrome, Firefox, IE and Edge on both Windows and Linux - yet I have also seen the correct rendering on all of these browsers.  I have also seen different outcomes on machines which are using the same version of the same browser.

I have tried pasting the character directly into the HTML as well as using the escape code `&scaron;`, both of which result in the same issue.

- Does anyone have any idea what could be causing the issue?
- Are there any suitable workarounds if it is not possible to rectify the issue?

Answer (score 3):

If a character isn't available in your webfont, a browser will look at which other fonts are on the stack, and pick one from there. You didn't post your CSS, but say it looks like this:

`font-family: palanquin, arial, sans-serif;`

For the "š", the browser would first try Arial. If Arial is present, *and* contains the š-character, it will render it as Arial. If the OS doesn't have Arial installed (like Linux or Android), it will continue on to the generic `sans-serif` font.

And this is where stuff get unreliable: it's now up to the browser to use *any* font it deems usable. Chrome on OSX will most likely use a different font than Chrome on Windows 10. This can vary for every browser version on every OS. A browser will even use a different generic `sans-serif` fallback for different languages: if the `lang` attribute is set to English, it might use a different font than when the language is set to Polish.

And some of these fonts will have fatter, smaller, thinner, wider versions of the letters. That's why in the first screenshot it looks like a very close match to Palanquin, but in the second the fallback font doesn't match Palanquin at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - my question however is why this is happening when the font _does_ contain the character in question, and _does_ display correctly on many browsers?